# ADF managed Airflow – ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, airflow

I created Azure Data Factory managed Airflow instance and loaded DAGs into.

Folder structure:

```
airflow/
    dags/
        __init__.py
        my_dag.py
        scripts/
            __init__.py
            my_script.py
```

In `my_dag.py` I imported class from `my_script.py` as `from scripts.my_script import MyClass`.

But I still getting error:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/my_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/my_dag.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scripts.my_script import MyClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I did everything as in official [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/modules_management.html).

I even check PYTHONPATH with `airflow info`, and it's in default state.

Answer (score 1):

Your folder structure is not follow official sample.

Use something like:

```
dags/
    |
    |
    my_company/
              | __init__.py
              | scripts
              |            |  __init__.py
              |            | my_script.py
              |
              | my_custom_dags
                              | __init__.py
                              | my_dag.py
```

And

```
from my_company.scripts.my_script import MyClass
```